# responsive jquery sticky issues

Tags: javascript, jquery

I designed a sticky navbar header after scroll it's work very well but if my resuluiton size less than `768px` my sticky navbar doesn't work anymore except reload(refresh) page

**HTML**

```
<div class="sticky-checkin oteller-sticky">
              <div class="sticky-container">
                  <div class="row mt10">
                   <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-6 mb10">
                      <input type="text" name="oda-otel-giris"  class="oda-giris-cikis input-full-width sticky-oda-giris" placeholder="Giriş" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#popupCheckin">
                        <span class="oda-otel-giris"></span>
                   </div>
                   <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-6 ">
                     <input type="text" name="oda-otel-cikis"  class="oda-giris-cikis input-full-width sticky-oda-cikis" placeholder="Çıkış" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#popupCheckin">
                        <span class="oda-otel-giris"></span>
                   </div>
                 </div>
              </div><!-- sticky container-->
               <div class="modal fade fullscreen" id="popupCheckin"  tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                  <div class="modal-dialog otel-filtreleme-popup">
                      <div class="modal-content" style="color:#fff;">
                          <div class="modal-header" style="border:1px solid orange;">
                                  <h3>OTEL BUL</h3>
                                  <button type="button" class="close btn btn-link" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><i class="fa fa-close fa-lg" style="color:#faa82b;"></i></button> 
                                  <h4 class="modal-title text-center"><span class="sr-only">main navigation</span></h4>
                          </div>
                          <div class="modal-body otel-filtreleme-popup">
                              <div class="container-margin nomargin nopadding notopmargin">
                                  <div class="row">
                                      <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 otel-arama">
                                        <input type="text" name="oda-otel" id="oda-otel" class="oda-otel input-full-width" placeholder="Otel adını veya Bölgeyi yaz">
                                        <span class="oda-otel-icon"></span>
                                      </div>
                                  </div><!-- otel ara-->
                                  <div class="row mt10">
                                     <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6 mb10">
                                        <input type="text" name="oda-otel-giris" class="oda-giris-cikis input-full-width" placeholder="Giriş">
                                          <span class="oda-otel-giris"></span>
                                     </div>
                                     <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6">
                                       <input type="text" name="oda-otel-cikis" class="oda-giris-cikis input-full-width" placeholder="Çıkış">
                                          <span class="oda-otel-giris"></span>
                                     </div>
                                 </div><!-- otel giriş çıkış-->
                                 <div class="row ">
                                   <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
                                    <select name="oda-otel-kisi" id="oda-otel-kisi" class="oda-otel-kisi" style="display: none;">
                                      <option value="">Kişi</option>
                                      <option value="">1 Kişi</option>
                                      <option value="">2 Kişi</option>
                                      <option value="">3 Kişi</option>
                                    </select><div class="nice-select oda-otel-kisi" tabindex="0"><span class="current">Kişi</span><ul class="list"><li data-value="" class="option selected">Kişi</li><li data-value="" class="option">1 Kişi</li><li data-value="" class="option">2 Kişi</li><li data-value="" class="option">3 Kişi</li></ul></div><span class="oda-otel-kisi-icon"></span>
                                   </div>
                                   <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning otel-oda-sec" value="OTEL ARA">
                                  </div>
                                 </div><!-- otel kişi sayısı-->
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
                  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
              </div><!-- /.fullscreen -->
          </div><!-- sticky checkin-->
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
  if (!$(".hotel-search-box").length) {
     return false; //Check if the element exist
  }
  if($(window).scrollTop() > $(".hotel-search-box").offset().top+$(".hotel-search-box").height() && $("#otel-checkin").val() == ""){
          $(".sticky-checkin").fadeIn(500);
      }else{
          $(".sticky-checkin").fadeOut(500);
      }
  });
});
```

CSS

```
   .sticky-checkin{
        position:fixed;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        z-index:1042;
        background:#FFF;
        width:100%;
        padding:15px 0;
        @include clearfix;
     -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 10px 7px -9px rgba(61,61,61,0.36);
    -moz-box-shadow: -1px 10px 7px -9px rgba(61,61,61,0.36);
    box-shadow: -1px 10px 7px -9px rgba(61,61,61,0.36);
    display:none;
    }
    .sticky-container{
        width:50%;
        position: relative;
        margin:0 auto;
        @include clearfix;
        input,select{
            cursor:pointer;
        }
    }
```

[click to see online demo](http://yurtici.anitur.com.tr/musteri/ingoing/2016/test/otel-listeleme.html)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/link2pk/25pdt6sx/8/ is that what you are looking for?
I replicated your problem so that I could know what's going on.

Comment: @link2pk I replaced my js but nothing change problem going on already but thanks your helping

Comment: I know this way but to work it page must be reloaded..

Comment: this jsfiddle is show/hiding the div without page refresh/reload.

Comment: I noticed but if I replaced my js with your js mine works as before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue lies in *display: none* property. Upon downsizing the window your sticky container get's hidden. However when you restore your browser to full window this property remains unchanged.

I would suggest checking your CSS rules and JS handling of window resize (if any).

**EDIT:** Your header is broken because of it's *display* property. `<div style="display: HERE GET'S COMPLICATED;" class="sticky-checkin oteller-sticky">`. When resizing, it retrieves value *none* which stays set no matter the windows size change. However there is another thing. If you scroll down so this header is displayed, it will set it's value to *block*. At this point, try resizing the window and header will stay on until refreshing the page.
There is too much code for me to properly debug it, so try to isolate code responsible for header's display.

Comment: I didn't use any window resize or something like that and my main div is not display:none on responsive and desktop

Comment: it's already display none every time but it just not working on responsive which code that I have to change ? I added my css codes..by the way thanks for helping

Comment: Display property is not set until first _fadeIn_ is fired. If I'm not mistaken, you are using some sort of plug-in for the header. I am sorry but I can not debug it as is. If you happen to isolate the problem, I'd be more than happy to help.

Comment: there is no plugin on the header for my sticky but for navigation menu I'm using a plugin maybe problem can be z-index? thank @casual

Comment: It's not just z-index. Once you resize, your `sticky-checkin` class won't change `display` property at all. Try putting `console.log("Scrolling away");` inside `if($(window).scrollTop()...` and see if there is anything getting printed out in the console.

Comment: but my sticky-checkin class is chancing on desktop am I wrong ?

Comment: and i I refresh page my sticky is working but without refresh is not working there is something interesting..

Comment: As I've said. If `sticky-checkin` retrieves a display property of none on window resize, it won't change it until you refresh your page. First step would be to check your scroll function as I've suggested in the comment above.

Comment: but there is one thing more..I delet my js codes and I paste on console it works very well I guess I have to change place of js hanks

Comment: I control my js function but I did nothing to do because there is no window resize function on muy js ?

Comment: Check your scroll function like so:
`$(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
if (!$(".hotel-search-box").length) {
     return false; //Check if the element exist
  }
  console.log("Scrolling away.");
  if($(window).scrollTop() > $(".hotel-search-box").offset().top+$(".hotel-search-box").height() && $("#otel-checkin").val() == "")}
console.log("Fade in.");
          $(".sticky-checkin").fadeIn(500);
      }else{
console.log("Fade in.");
          $(".sticky-checkin").fadeOut(500);
      }
  });
});`. And report how does it go before and after resize.

Comment: Invalid or unexpected token

Comment: Here you go:
https://jsfiddle.net/80chfkv4/
Test it out and report what gets printed out in the console.

Comment: ok..this code doesn't work on mobile..it work's on desktop after I refresh the page..and I added new demo you can see there

Comment: sorry..it's working both on mobile and dekstop but after refresh

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122828/discussion-between-casual-and-fortherest).

Comment: and print;
scrolling away
main.js:171 fade out
main.js:166 scrolling away
main.js:171 fade out
main.js:166 scrolling away
main.js:171 fade out
main.js:166 scrolling away
main.js:171 fade out
main.js:166 scrolling away
main.js:171 fade out
main.js:166 scrolling away
main.js:171 fade out
main.js:166 scrolling away
main.js:171 fade out
main.js:166 scrolling away
main.js:171 fade out
main.js:166 scrolling away
main.js:171 fade out